# Dropdown menu option to add a 'required' class to another dropdown menu but remove the class for the other options when selected

Tags: jquery, forms, class, select, required

I needed certain fields to be 'required' so have used jquery.validate.js and class="required" etc.

Only problem is I have made the form extend when a certain option is chosen on a dropdown input by making a hidden div become visible using: Display:None and then Display: Block.

One of the fields in the extended div needs to be a required field but if I set it as class="required".  The validation will still require a value from this field even when it is hidden and not needed.

**So, what I need to do is have the class="required" be added or removed or toggled on change of the watched select input which appears in the form at all times.**

Here is how I have tried to code it but it does not seem to be working
Big thanks to anyone who can help and I hope I have made sense in my explanation.

This first bit extends the form by displaying a hidden div on selection of the drop down options.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    // <![CDATA[ 
    function display(obj,id1,id2,id3) { 
    txt = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value; 
    document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementById(id3).style.display = 'none'; 
    if ( txt.match(id1) ) { 
    document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'block'; 
    } 
    if ( txt.match(id2) ) { 
    document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'block'; 
    } 
    if ( txt.match(id3) ) { 
    document.getElementById(id3).style.display = 'block'; 
    }  
    } 
    // ]]> 
    </script> 

    // This is how I have tried to add & remove the required class.

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#category').change(function(){
        if ( $('#category').val() =='id1' ) {
        $('#size').addClass('required');
    } else {
        $('#size').removeClass('required');
    }
    }

    </script>


    <html>

    <form class="orderform" action="FormNext.php" method="post" name="OrderForm" id="OrderForm">


    <select id="category" name="category" class="required" onchange="display(this,'id1','id2','id3');">
                                      <option value="">- please select -</option>
                                      <option value="id1">Category1</option>
                                      <option value="id2">Category2</option>
                                      <option value="id3">Category3</option>
    </select>



<div id="id1">

    <select name="size" id="size" class="">
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option value="xsmall">extra small </option>
      <option value="small">small </option>
      <option value="medium">medium</option>
      <option value="large">large </option>
      <option value="xlarge">extra large</option>
    </select>

</div>
    </form>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>  
    function display(obj,id1,id2,id3) { 
        txt = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value; 
        document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'none'; 
        document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'none'; 
        document.getElementById(id3).style.display = 'none'; 
        if ( txt.match(id1) ) {
            document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'block'; 
        } 
        if ( txt.match(id2) ) { 
            document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'block'; 
        } 
        if ( txt.match(id3) ) { 
            document.getElementById(id3).style.display = 'block'; 
        }  
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#category').change(function(){
            var selectedValue = $('#category').val();
            $('#size').removeClass('required');
            $('#' + selectedValue + ' > select').addClass('required');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form class="orderform" action="FormNext.php" method="post" name="OrderForm" id="OrderForm">


<select id="category" name="category" class="required" onchange="display(this,'id1','id2','id3');">
    <option value="">- please select -</option>
    <option value="id1">Category1</option>
    <option value="id2">Category2</option>
    <option value="id3">Category3</option>
</select>



<div id="id1" style="display:none">

    <select name="size" id="size" class="">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="xsmall">extra small </option>
        <option value="small">small </option>
        <option value="medium">medium</option>
        <option value="large">large </option>
        <option value="xlarge">extra large</option>
    </select>

</div>
<div id="id2" style="display:none">

    <select name="size" id="size" class="">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="xsmall">extra small </option>
        <option value="small">small </option>
        <option value="medium">medium</option>
        <option value="large">large </option>
        <option value="xlarge">extra large</option>
    </select>

</div>
<div id="id3" style="display:none">

    <select name="size" id="size" class="">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="xsmall">extra small </option>
        <option value="small">small </option>
        <option value="medium">medium</option>
        <option value="large">large </option>
        <option value="xlarge">extra large</option>
    </select>

</div>
</form>
```

I assume you missed # for size and category. try and let me know

# is used to select by id and . is used to select tag by classname and if you want to select element then its mentioned directly.

```
Like this
$('#id').doStuff();
$('.className').doStuff();
$(div).doStuff();
$('[name="ElementNameHere"]').doStuff();
```

Comment: There is also a small issue with the validation rule. A select element always has a value so will always meet the required condition. You may want to add in a ...val() !== ""

Comment: I have changed it many times so didnt realise in my post the calling of id, class or element itself is maybe not consistent.  This could be why it is not working but I am looking to find out which of these  I should be calling for it to work. I am new to coding so I apologise If I am making little sense. 

Does this javascript look close to working in relation to the question and outcome above.

Comment: oh... have to go through in that case

Comment: in reply to  darronz Is it not ok just to give the first option in a menu value="" because this seems to work with the first of the two select menus it will stop the form submitting if left on the first option as is the equivalent of an empty value.

Comment: I have now changed the javascript code so that it is only calling the #id of inputs.  Still does not seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far.  As far as I can see it looks like the code should work.  

It is an IF statement that says IF #category's value is 'id1' add the required class to #size otherwise remove the required class.  What else could be stopping it?  Or should it be coded differently.

Comment: first of all the code os poorly structured, you need to work on that, I'm trying to fix your issue, will let you know soon

Comment: save this as an html file and see

Comment: It is not my full page code so I can understand it most likely would not work at all as does not include the validation part and the full form but I assumed the problem might have been easy to spot in my bodged javascript coding for the addClass and removeClass Function.

I can post the validation script if needed maybe it can be set as a rule: of the size field to be 'required: true IF.... Dont know if something like that is possible.

Comment: I hope the solution solved you purpose now you can take it ahead from here

Comment: thanks for trying SirwaniMayur.  Il search further for some examples of similar functions that work to try and fix the problem.

Comment: but the problem is fixed, what you asked for has been done fred

Comment: ah sorry I missed that and thanks alot I will check this now.

Comment: im not sure yet.  I have not got it to work yet with my full code with submit button etc but I will let you know.  Check back later.  Looks as though it should work and obviously a lot better structured.  Thanks.

Comment: I would but have only recentley signed up on here and do not have enough reputation points yet to upvote.